# Why doesn't window.scroll() and window.width() work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, width

Why doesn't these functions work together? I want to change box-shadow when the page is scrolled and the window width is less then 960px.

```
function hasScroll() {
    $('.fixed').css({
        "height": "50px",
        "box-shadow": "0px 79px 31px white"
    });
}
function changeShadow() {
    $('.fixed').css({
        "height": "50px",
        "box-shadow": "-3px 48px 44px white"
    });
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        hasScroll();
    }
    else if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && $(window).width() < 960) {
        changeShadow();
    }
    else{
        notSctoll();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `if/else` construction. When `scrollTop()` returns a value more then 100, first condition will always be satisfied. Due to this, `if else` statement would not be touched. It will be touched only if first `if` condition fails.

Try to change first `if` to:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && $(window).width() > 960)
```